# Propertygrid collection multiselect - Show all values

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have object instances each containing a collection property. When they are selected individually, the property values are displayed as key value pair. The first column (name) is read only and second column (path) can be edited.

[image]

When two error sets are selected simultaneously, the first property is empty as second property of both instances are same. Is it possible to show all the properties when the collections are unequal as shown below?

[image]

Comment: which property grid?

Comment: I am using a custom property grid. Is it possible to show different views on multi selection?